# jquery functions doesn´t work after external loading

Tags: ajax, function, jquery, external, thickbox

I have a website.. with three div columns, colA colB and colC.

on colA i have a menu that triggers some ajax functions to load text on colC and thumnails on colB.

it works perfect.. here it is a piece of code.

```
var loading = $(".loading");
var content = $("#colC");   
var thumbs = $("#colB");

    $("#menu li a").click(function(){ 

    showLoading();

 switch(this.id){
    case "home":
        content.load("content.php #home", hideLoading);
    thumbs.load("products.php #prodA", hideLoading);
        break;

    case "about":
        ....
        break;

    case "...":
        ....
        break;

    });
```

the problem is.. that #prodA from products.php brings to the website new jquery functions (thickbox) and they doesn´t work at all.

i tried this:

```
$("#menu li a").live("click", function(){
```

and nothing happened..

then i tried using the js file for livequery:

```
$("#menu li a").livequery("click", function(){
```

and nothing happened neither.

so.. i'm all ears to hear from you guys to help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Thickbox plugin is registering all the 'thickbox' page elements at run time. If you dynamically add elements later they wont be triggered by the thickbox call. I had a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080581/what-is-wrong-with-my-flimsy-ajax-file-upload/1081001#1081001).