# What is wrong with my Flimsy AJAX File Upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know you can not do an AJAX File Upload but this just a name I have chosen to use. :)

I am making use of [this JQuery plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). I think the main problem is I am using it in a slightly different context. Here is how I use it and I think this is the problem.

I first make a form:

```
$("#flash").html("<input id='vidup' type='file' name='file' size='10' /><input type='button' name='submit' onclick='videoUpload();' value='Upload' />");
```

I click on the button will call this videoUpload function which makes an AJAX request to get a variable which is the URL to upload to, this is dynamically created:

```
function videoUpload(){
    $.get("getUploader.php", function(data){
    new AjaxUpload('#vidup', {
          action: data,
          name: 'myfile',
          responseType: 'xml',
          onSubmit: function() {
            // allow only 1 upload
            alert('onSubmit' + data);
            this.disable();
          },
          onComplete: function(file, response){
              alert('Response' + response);
          }
        });
    });
}
```

However, the only thing that happens is that hidden field is created titled 'myfile' but none of my alerts show up! The creator of the plugin is making use of it via the "$(document).ready(function()" and I am not, will this cause a problem?

Please ask questions as I do not know what other info to give!

Thanks all

### Update

It manages to add the input field with this markup:

```
    <input type="file" name="myfile" style="margin: -5px 0pt 0pt -175px; 
padding: 0pt; position: absolute; width: 220px; height: 30px; font-size: 14px; 
opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 2147483583;"/>
```

However, it doesn't proceed to upload the file. I thought it should have also created an iFrame?

Comment: do you get the data from the get request from getUploader.php?

Comment: Yes, I do. It returns exactly what I need and the AJAX upload even manages to create a textfield but does not do anything after that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin is registered at ready() time. At that time your #flash div is empty. You can [modify](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) the plugin probably binding the call to other event, but this is not a very good idea, or just create the div from php to be there when ready() is called. The same thing happen to me with the Thickbox plugin. I dont really think is a good idea for plugin developers to register actions at ready() as a lot of content can be generated afterwards.

Comment: Thank your reply. I am still confused. I only call the videoUpload() method when my flash div contains the input text field and submit button, so its not empty. I don't understand the tutorial and I am getting frustrated - I think I am going to pull my own teeth out, hmm...

Comment: Actually the plugin is read and executed when is loaded and not when you call it. At runtime he searches and identifies a working set that will use whenever you call for it in your code.

Comment: Really? I can't understand it. It is wrapped in a function which I call. Please explain more or just say you are 100% sure so I can try to figure out from there. Thank you for any more help. :)

Comment: Yes. If you are using Firebug to debug and add 2 breaking points, one in the plugin at the _createIframe function and one in the html at the "new AjaxUpload" point you'll see that the _createIframe is executed before the other call.

Comment: Ok I am just doing that, you seem sure. So the way to stop this from happening is use bind events??

Comment: You can't bind the plugin events. You can either rewrite the plugin, either have the input field present already when the plugin is read.

Comment: Genius, your second suggestion of having it ready worked for me. I could just cry with relief - thank you for sticking with me. You deserve more rep!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that my problem was similar, but i was tackling to use colorbox on jquery created links. It didn't work because of the plugins document ready usage. Then i tried this and it worked.

```
function colorbox() {
                $('.gf-title').colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
            };


            $(window).load(function(){
                colorbox();              
            });
```